# Error when trying to Serialize a ManyToMany relationship (Django with DRF)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, manytomanyfield

I'm getting an error when I try to serialize a many-to-many relationship

The error description that is shown to me in the console is this:

AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `produto` on serializer `Ped_ProSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Produto` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Produto' object has no attribute 'produto'.

The models involved in the relationship are written like this:

```
class Produto(models.Model):
    valor_unitario = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    descricao = models.TextField()
    genero = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="Indefinido")
    qtd_estoque = models.IntegerField()
    cor = models.ForeignKey(Cor, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="produtos")
    tamanho = models.ForeignKey(
        Tamanho, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="produtos"
    )
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="produtos")

class Pedido(models.Model):
    endereco_entrega = models.ForeignKey(
        Endereco, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, related_name="pedidos"
    )
    forma_pagamento = models.ForeignKey(
        Forma_Pagamento, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, related_name="pedidos"
    )
    usuario_dono = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(), on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="pedidos"
    )
    data_entrega = models.DateField()
    data_pedido = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    finalizado = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    qtd_parcela = models.IntegerField()
    valor_parcela = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    preco_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0.00)
    itens = models.ManyToManyField(Produto, related_name="pedidos", through="Ped_Pro")

class Ped_Pro(models.Model):
    produto = models.ForeignKey(
        Produto, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="ped_pros"
    )
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(
        Pedido, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="ped_pros"
    )
    qtd_produto = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    data_entrada = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

The serializers:

```
class ProdutoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Produto
        fields = "__all__"


class Ped_ProSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ped_Pro
        fields = "__all__"


class PedidoSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    itens = Ped_ProSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Pedido
        fields = "__all__"
```

Could you help me find a way to the solution?

[Project link on Github](https://www.github.com/ericopieri/django-projetointegrador)

Comment: Are all migrations applied? Try running `makemagirations` and `migrate` again

Comment: Yes, all migrations are applied.

Comment: Your error message does not match the models you have, it's difficult to say for sure what the error is if you don't provide the "exact" logs.

Comment: I tried to update

Answer (score 0):

In class ped pro you have 2 times the same related name: ped_pros